# Python StatsModel OLS with Effect Tests

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm using statsmodels to perform Multiple Linear Regression on a continuous DV with categorical IVs.

I'm also using dummy variables for the categorical variables, which is working well. The problem I have is that I only get the un-grouped results, but I'm not sure how to get the grouped effect tests.

So I get this OLS result (using fictional numbers):

|  | coef | ... | P>t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| const | -0.5 | ... | 0.55 |
| Fruit_Apple | 0.512 | ... | 0.53 |
| Fruit_Banana | 0.027 | ... | 0.51 |
| Fruit_Pear | -0.15 | ... | 0.001 |
| Sale | -0.35 | ... | 0.25 |
| Color_Red | 1.7 | ... | 0.006 |
| Color_Yellow | -0.11 | ... | 0.04 |

But how do I get this as well:

|  | F Ratio | Prob > F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | 1.46 | 0.1993 |
| Sale | 16.16 | 0.0002 |
| Color | 1.99 | 0.1479 |

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to run an F-test for joint significance.

Suppose your fitted OLS object resides in `result`:

```
result = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

Specify the hypothesis, e.g.:

```
hypothesis = '(Fruit_Apple = 0), (Fruit_Banana = 0), (Fruit_Pear = 0)'
```

Then perform F-test and view results:

```
f_test = result.f_test(hypothesis)
print(f_test)
```